ERROR RangeError: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties, js engine: hermes
After running my app for several hours, the message "ERROR RangeError: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties, js engine: hermes" appears. However, this problem is not present in the release build as I am using react native.
I've noticed this kind of issue in a few apps; is it something to do with my emulator or is there a package issue?

This looks to be a bug in hermes: github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39441

i also got it on react native 0.74 ,but it is only on development
